# Where do I run Python code for frame io API?

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm not understanding this first simple concept if you could help me please.

I'm trying to learn the frame.io API to so some simple things like scrape comments using Python.

I have a frame.io dev token and I have Python installed on my Mac.

Where do I actually run the code. Terminal? Do I use IDLE or Python launcher?

I've been working with JavaScript up until now so I'm a little confused.

Comment: IDLE or any IDE is meant for exploring the language and editing code.  Production running should usually be done directly, without the IDE.

Comment: Generally, you would write your code with any text editor, then run `python myscript.py` from a command prompt.